# VueJs, Vuefire, Firestore: How can I filter a synched Firestore document

Tags: vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

Using vuefire allows me to set a firestore object on the vue instance and automatically syncs it with Firestore. I ALSO want to filter that for another data point but filtering causes an error.

The code below returns the staff which is desired and working perfectly. The Firebase User (fbUser) returns

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__services_Firebase**.a.collection(...).filter
>   is not a function

and the datapoint is empty in VueTools

```
firestore() {
    return {
        staff: db.collection('staff').orderBy('lastname'),
        fbUser: db.collection('staff').filter(s => s.email === this.current_user.email)
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection` doesn't returns directly the result. I don't know the implementation, but I suppose `vuefire` will create a data field named `fbUser` and save result in it.

I think, the best solution is to use computed data like:

```
computed: {
    fbUserFiltered () {
        return this.fbUser.filter(s => s.email === this.current_user.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old question but I had the same issue and wanted a more general answer.*

If you want to avoid querying the whole collection only to discard non-matching results on the client, you can use the `$bind()` function in your `created()` event, e.g.

```js
  data: () => ({
    finance_staff: [],
  }),

  created() {
    const filtered_entries = db.collection('staff').where('department', '==', 'finance');
    this.$bind('finance_staff', filtered_entries);
  },
```

Or if you need to wait for auth state:

```js
  created() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if (!user) return;
      const filtered_entries = db.collection('staff').where('manager_id', '==', user.uid);
      this.$bind('my_staff', filtered_entries);
    });
  },
```

Note that if you already knew the document ID, then it would be even simpler:

```js
  firestore: {
    current_employee: db.collection("staff").doc("abcd1234")
  },
```